# Multiple downloads async

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

In java I want to download multiple images for my imageview at once. I found this code which does exact that but its only downloading the first image. I think it has something to do with the first line in the doInBackground. How can I tweak this code so it loops imageViews and downloads every image for imageViews.

```
package com.denederlandsewateren.daos;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DownloadImageTaskDAO extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap> {

    ImageView imageView = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
        this.imageView = imageViews[0];
        return download_Image((String)imageView.getTag());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {
        //---------------------------------------------------
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Hub","Error getting the image from server : " + e.getMessage().toString());
        } 
        return bm;
        //---------------------------------------------------
    }

}
```

called from here:

```
public void setImages(String url1, String url2) {
        image1.setTag(url1);
        image2.setTag(url2);
        DownloadImageTaskDAO imageDAO = new DownloadImageTaskDAO();
        imageDAO.execute(image1, image2);
    }
```

Comment: If you're interested, there's also a library available to do this sort of thing for you. https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

Comment: Change your AsyncTask to do all in your doInBackground, don't do your AsyncTask return a ImageView etc. Then you can go through your Array setting the images, or pass to AsyncTask the position in the array that you want to load, and then before call the asynctask do the loop, the second opinion I think is better, 'cause you will have  more than one asynctask getting images simultaneous.

Comment: the github lib worked for me. Quick and easy implementation. Post it as a answer so I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
    this.imageView = imageViews[0];
    return download_Image((String)imageView.getTag());
}
```

You are processing only the first argument sent to the AsyncTask. With the parameter `ImageView...` you can send one, two, N elements or arrays. Loop through the arguments and process each one.

You can use the return from `doInBackground`, in `onPostExecute` and personally I try to utilize that as much as I can for the sake of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Overall I suggest you read the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) reference on Android Developers to get a better understanding of AsyncTasks.

I did rewrite your code and below should theoretically work (it's not tested).

```
public class DownloadImageTaskDAO extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, ArrayList<DownloadImageTaskDAO.Container>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Container> doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
         ArrayList<Container> results = new ArrayList<Container>(imageViews.length);

         for (ImageView imageView : imageViews) {
             Container tmp = new Container();
             tmp.holder = imageView;
             tmp.image = download_Image(imageView.getTag().toString());
             results.add(tmp);
         }

         return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Container> result) {
        for (Container container : result) {
            container.holder.setImageBitmap(container.image);
        }
    }

    private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {
        ....
    }

    class Container {
        ImageView holder;
        Bitmap image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use an AsyncTask, instead consider using a IntentService with a ResultReceiver passed as an extra to the service.  IntentService's perform better under load (like downloading multiple images) because they use HandlerThread's as opposed to AsyncTasks which use ThreadPoolExecutor.

[IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

[ResultReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html)

Answer (score 0):

i suggest this way to implement your code

Hope it will helpfull to you  download `Multiple images` with single `AsyncTask` call.

**Asynctask Call Method**

```
public void setImages(String[] urls)
{
   DownloadImageTaskDAO imageDAO = new DownloadImageTaskDAO();

   if(int i= 0; i< urls.lenght();i++)
   {
        image.setTag(urls[i]);
        imageDAO.execute(image).get();
    }
}
```

**DownloadImageTaskDAO Class :**

```
public class DownloadImageTaskDAO extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap> {

    ImageView imageView = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
        return download_Image((String)imageView.getTag());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {
        //---------------------------------------------------
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Hub","Error getting the image from server : " + e.getMessage().toString());
        } 
        return bm;
        //---------------------------------------------------
    }

}
```

Comment: jep... that works to. However i prefer the library since its just 1 one line of code without a forloop.
Good answer though!